# Formula that uses range size based on other cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In Excel I do a text join for a bunch of 'tags' for each unique id from an export from another system.

***Data example:***
[image]

Currently I change the range in the TEXTJOIN formula for the amount of times the given ID occurs (aka number of tags).

I want an autofill formula that I can double click and have it fill down only using the text join the first time for unique id so I can delete duplicates and have all the tags for each id.

Currently I drag this formula `=TEXTJOIN(";";TRUE;"A2:A5")` down until the amount of tags changes, then edit the formula and drag down again.

I want to end up with a single occurrence of each unique id with all the associated tags so I can import it.

Comment: And do you need the result on the same worksheet? If so, then you will have to insert the formula at the first occurrence of each TicketID, which still needs manual work.

Comment: As suggested above, do you really need it in the way you show? It is easy to use a VBA solution able to extract only unique TicketID, followed by the corresponding tasks. Wouldn't it be better?

Answer (score 3):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=MAP(A2:A17,
LAMBDA(x,
IF(COUNTIFS(A2:INDEX(A:A,ROW(x)),x)=1,
TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(B2:B17,A2:A17=x)),"")
))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since `TEXTJOIN()` function will render error when it surpasses `character limitations` hence avoiding to use the dynamic spill array and opting to use the fill down regular formulas with `TEXTJOIN()` and `FILTER()` with running `COUNTIF()` also I would highly suggest in using `Power Query` where it will be dynamic, flexible and one time approach, so whenever you add new data to the source, you need to only refresh the imported data from `Power Query`

---

**Using Excel Formulas:**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=TEXTJOIN(
    "; ",
    ,
    FILTER(
        $C$2:$C$17,
        (A2 = $A$2:$A$17) *
            (
                COUNTIF(
                    A$2:A2,
                    A2
                ) = 1
            ),
        ""
    )
)
```

---

The above formula needs to be filled down respectively in order to get the desired outputs.

---

**Using Power Query:**

[image]

---

To perform the above task using **Power Query** follow the steps:

• First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as **Table1**

---

• Next, open a blank query from `Data Tab` --> `Get & Transform Data` --> `Get Data` --> `From Other Sources` --> `Blank Query`

---

• The above lets the `Power Query` window opens, now from `Home Tab` --> `Advanced Editor` --> And paste the following by removing whatever you see, and press `Done`

**M-Code:**

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"TicketId"}, {{"All", each _, type table [TicketId=text, COUNTIF=text, Tag=text]}, {"Sum", each Text.Combine([Tag],"; "), type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"COUNTIF", "Tag", "Index"}, {"COUNTIF", "Tag", "Index"}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Result", each if [Index] = 1 then [Sum] else null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Conditional Column",{"All", "Sum", "Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

• Lastly, to import it back to `Excel` --> Click on `Close & Load` or `Close & Load To` --> The first one which clicked shall create a new sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=MAP(A2:A17,LAMBDA(s,IF(ROW(s)=XMATCH(s,A:A),TEXTJOIN(";",,FILTER(C:C,A:A=s)),"")))
```

---

**PowerQuery:**

For fun my attempt without grouping:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    Step1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TicketID", Int64.Type}, {"COUNTIF", type any}, {"Tag", type text}}),
    Step2 = Table.AddIndexColumn(Step1, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    Step3 = Table.AddColumn(Step2, "Custom", each let l=Table.Column(Step2,"TicketID") in if List.Combine({{0},l}){[Index]}<>l{[Index]} then Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Numbers(0,List.Count(l)),(n)=> if [TicketID]=l{n} then Table.Column(Step2,"Tag"){n} else null),";") else null),
    Step4 = Table.RemoveColumns(Step3,{"Index"})
in
    Step4
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

And a VBA solution (also tagged), building a range containing only the necessary data (without spaces between the following ID. Please use the next function. If Excel 365 (2019) it can be used as UDF (User Defined Function), too, The range may be **not sorted**:

```
Function ExtractTags(rngTg As Range) As Variant
  Dim arr, i As Long, dict As Object
  
 arr = rngTg.Value2 'place the range (without header) in an array, for faster processing
 
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary to extract unique keys
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate (in memory) and load dictionary with unique keys and tag Items per key:
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
        dict.Add arr(i, 1), arr(i, 3)
    Else
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) & ";" & arr(i, 3)
    End If
 Next i
  'create a 2D array from the dictionary elements (keys and items)
  ExtractTags = Application.Transpose(Array(dict.keys, dict.Items))
End Function
```

It can be used as UDF, placing a formula in the range where to start returning:

```
  =ExtractTags(A2:C15)
```

For Excel version not being able to return arrays, please use the next sub:

```
Sub testExtractTags()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = ExtractTags(Range("A2:C" & lastR))
   
   With ws.Range("E1:F1")
        .Value2 = Array("TicketID", "Tag") 'place the header
        .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arr)).Value2 = arr 'drop the processed array content
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit              'autofit the two involved columns
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if the data is sorted by "TicketId" then this type can be used. It uses: TEXTJOIN, ROW, INDIRECT and COUNTIF

In cell D2:

```
=IF(OR(A1=A2;A1="";A2="");"";TEXTJOIN(";";TRUE;INDIRECT("C" & ROW() & ":C" & ROW()+COUNTIF(A:A;A2)-1)))
```

[image]